# Why isn't my slide background image displaying?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't my slide background image displaying? The issue isn't the file path it's the coding.

When the slide one appears I wan't my image to show at the moment I have a white background as the image isn't displaying.

```css
/* Styling and fetching IMG */

.slide-1 {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)), url('media/image/slider/audi-black-car-8639.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="rev_slider_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container">
  <div id="rev_slider" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.0.7">
    <ul>
      <li data-index="slide-1" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="500" data-rotate="0" data-delay="6000">
        <img class="pic_slide_one" alt="slide-1" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center bottom">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code its working fine. please add the css to class attribute in html and make sure display is block instead of none.

```css
.slide-1 {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)), url('media/image/slider/audi-black-car-8639.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="rev_slider_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container">
  <div id="rev_slider" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner" style="display:block;" data-version="5.0.7">
    <ul>
      <li class ="slide-1" data-index="slide-1" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="500" data-rotate="0" data-delay="6000">
        <img class="pic_slide_one" alt="slide-1" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center bottom">
```